# Label Encoder can't 'see' previously 'seen' labels

Tags: python, scikit-learn, label-encoding

I need to encode a column having 4 classes i.e., Education with classes Bachelor's, Master's, PhD, and High School. When I fit the label encoder to the training set (tr, here) and transform the test set (cv, here) I get the error that goes

```
Error: y contains previously unseen labels: "PhD"
```

I understand that the error implies that the training set doesn't contain all 4 classes and thus when the encoder comes across the 4th one in the validation set, it throws the above error, but that isn't the case:

```
tr_df['Education'].value_counts()
Bachelor's     45084
High School    44751
PhD            44586
Master's       44321
Name: Education, dtype: int64
```

and

```
cv_df['Education'].value_counts()
Bachelor's     19282
Master's       19220
High School    19152
PhD            18951
Name: Education, dtype: int64
```

I tried going the other way around as well: fitting the cv_df and transforming the tr_df dataset
I got

```
Error: y contains previously unseen labels: "Bachelor's"
```

Please let me know what is actually happening here

```
encodable_columns = ['Education', 'EmploymentType', 'MaritalStatus', 
                     'HasMortgage', 'HasDependents', 'LoanPurpose', 'HasCoSigner']
le = LabelEncoder()
encoded_df = cv_df[encodable_columns].apply(le.fit_transform)
cv_df.drop(columns=encodable_columns, axis=1, inplace=True)
cv_df = pd.concat([tr_df, encoded_df], axis=1)
```

and

```
encoded_df = tr_df[encodable_columns].apply(le.transform)
tr_df.drop(columns=encodable_columns, axis=1, inplace=True)
tr_df = pd.concat([tr_df, encoded_df], axis=1)
```

Threw the error:

```
ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: "Bachelor's"
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to you trying to fit and transform each row of the dataframe: when you do `encoded_df = cv_df[encodable_columns].apply(le.fit_transform)`.

Try instead to work on the whole column instead, as follows:

```py
for col in encodable_columns:
    label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
    cv_df[col] = label_encoder.fit_transform(cv_df[col])
```

If you wish you can encode to a different column name, and then concatenate as you do.

Comment: You need to _save_ all those different label encoders four transforming the test set later. But `OrdinalEncoder` is the right class for transforming `X`, and it handles multiple columns fine.

Comment: You were right @BenReiniger , I needed to have 7 Label Encoders for my task there and so Ordinal Encoder did the trick instead, thank you very much! 
But I wonder how come this class isn't as popular as the others, seeing that my task above is pretty generic...?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in a different project. What I suggest, to avoid any trouble, is to give a look at the documentation and map all the categorical features by hand.
(You can also check [OneHotEncoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), which might cause the database to have too many features or [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html), as you did, for off-the-shelf solution)

My idea is instead to check all possible values (from available sources) and then doing something like:

```
# Mapping for encoding
education_mapping = {'Bachelor\'s': 0, 'Master\'s': 1, 'PhD': 2, 'High School': 3}  # <-- All possible categories should be here

# Apply mapping to the columns with categorical data in both training and test sets
tr['Education_encoded'] = tr['Education'].map(education_mapping)
cv['Education_encoded'] = cv['Education'].map(education_mapping)
```

P.S. Fitting or doing such things using the test or validation dataset is 'illegal' xD